# Win8 Compass, false readings

Tags: windows-8, sensors, compass-geolocation, tablet-pc

I have been confused for a long time by the Compass in Windows 8.

I knew that there is a API called "Compass" in `Devices.Sensors`, and I can use it to get the the compass reading as a magnetic-north or true-north value.
You can see a sample in Microsoft help: ([Compass sensor sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Compass-Sensor-Sample-0ed09c55))!

The problem is the value is not correct at all and the value is almost ridiculous.

To get more information, I searched some apps in Windows 8 APP STORES. I found some similar compass apps, such as "Quick Compass"/"Simple Compass"/"Compass APP"
The values from these apps are the same as mine. They are all not correct.

The devices I tested are Surface and Tablet2.

So I would like to get some help from you. If you ever used compass API and did some related research about Windows 8 sensors. Please give me some clues.

Comment: What is your question? If all the other apps are failing as well that seems to be an indicator that the compass hardware is simply buggy.

Comment: I can not believe it is true. I have tried many devices, several surface and several tablet2. And try to contact the service of lenovo, he have not given me any reply. I think other reasons such as the API or other methods existed to adjust the value.